# How to calculate angular velocity from forces on spherical pendulum head?

Tags: forces, constrained-dynamics, spherical-harmonics

I have a bunch of forces that add up the force vector $(a_x, a_y, a_z)$ which is applied to the head of a spherical pendulum with given angles and angular velocities $ (\phi, \theta, \phi', \theta') $ and length $ l $.

How can I calculate the new angles and angular velocities after a timestep $ t $?

[image]

(image source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_pendulum))

Comment: Just solve the differential equation $\vec{s''(t)}=\vec{a}$ with the given initial conditions, better in polar coordinates